# Creating sparse matrix using R

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I have a csv file containing a userid, ISBN and bookrating seperated by ";". I want to show this data as a sparse matrix with userid as its rows, ISBN as its column and bookrating is its value.
I am using the as.matrix command but its not working. Here is my code.

```
matrix <- as.matrix(read.csv("BookRating.csv", nrows=50,sep=";",header=FALSE))
```

and the out put is like this:

```
  User.ID.ISBN.Book.Rating
1       276725;034545104X;0
2       276726;0155061224;5
3       276727;0446520802;0
4       276729;052165615X;3
5       276729;0521795028;6
6       276733;2080674722;0
7       276736;3257224281;8
```

can anybody tell me how can i build a sparse matrix?

Comment: set header as `TRUE` in your read.csv, as header is present in file

Comment: Your matrix here is not numeric. It doesn't make sense to create a sparse version of a matrix unless it is numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matrix package has a constructor made especially for your type of data:
first convert matrix into a data frame.

```
UIMatrix <- sparseMatrix(i = matrix$User.ID,
                         j = matrix$ISBN,
                         x = matrix$Book.Rating)
```

Comment: I  am getting an error: Error: unexpected ')' in "x = matrix$Book.Rating)"

Comment: convert the non numeric (categorical values) values to numeric. you can get details here [link](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/r-statistical-changing-categorical-variables-from-text-to-numbers.1147878/)